# Using Proguard With Android Studio problems generating signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'abc'
            keyPassword 'feet'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Nabasree/Desktop/mylocation')
            storePassword 'feet'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false

    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':glowPadView')
    compile project(':pullToRefreshListView')
    compile project(':librari')
    // compile ('com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:VERSION');
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicatorLib')
    compile files('libs/android-saripaar-1.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/com.haarman.listviewanimations-2.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-2.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/image-chooser-library-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.7.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/sugar-1.2.jar')
}
```

I have few library projects such as facebook. Both my project and the library use the same version of support library v13.

While generating a signed apk i am getting these errors

**Execution failed for task ':myapp:proguardRelease'.**

```
 java.io.IOException: Can't write [..\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar] (Can't read [..\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\F-Up\facebookSDK\unspecified\libs\android-support-v13.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v4/c/b.class == android-support-v13.jar:android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap$1.class]))
```

I have no clue how to solve this and generate a signed apk

Also went through the library projects libs folder and din't find android-support-v4.jar. All i have is android-support-v13.jar

Comment: Hi Nabasree, did you find a solution for the problem? I see exactly the same error now, I believe I'm pulling my hair like you did :[

Answer (score 2):

Don't reference the support library by including its jar directly; when you do this, the build system can't disambiguate between multiple versions of it, and you get errors of this type. Include it by referencing its Maven coordinates:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:X.X.X'
}
```

where `X.X.X` is the proper version number based on what API you're compiling against. If you include this dependency via the UI at **Project Structure > (your module) > Dependencies > + Button > Library dependency** it will help you choose the right version number.

You may also find it convenient to include other dependencies via Maven coordinates instead of wrangling their jars; that same library dependency UI has a search function to help you find libraries.

Comment: To add to this, be sure to remove this library from the libs or any other folder it was present inside

Answer (score 2):

I added support-v13 from SDK as mentioned above, direct library dependency not through lib folder.

Apart from the above changes, I did some modification in my `proguard-android.txt` file.

For third party libraries added:

```
-dontwarn android.support.**,com.example.**,com.example1.**
```

For facebook added:

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {
*;
}
```

Now, it's working fine.